# Visual Studio で呼び出し履歴に履歴が表示されない

Tags: visual-studio

デバッグしてアプリを適当に動かしても呼び出し履歴に履歴が表示されません。
表示されるようにするにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

アプリの言語：c#, c++, c
アプリの種類：デスクトップアプリ

Comment: 何の言語のどんなプログラムのデバッグのどのタイミングでどう表示されるはずとかの情報を追記してください。[デバッガーで呼び出し履歴を表示し、\[呼び出し履歴\] ウィンドウを使用する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019), [デバッグ時に呼び出し履歴のビジュアル マップを作成する (C#、Visual Basic、C++、JavaScript)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/map-methods-on-the-call-stack-while-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), [\[呼び出し履歴\] ウィンドウの混合コードと不足情報](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/mixed-code-and-missing-information-in-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019)

Comment: ビルド時にシンボルファイルを作成していますか？ [Visual Studio デバッガーでシンボル (.pdb) ファイルとソース ファイルを指定します (C#、C++、Visual Basic、F#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1):

> 適当に動かしても

の文言がすごく気になります。具体的にどうしたが無いので妄想レベルにとどまりますが

- 呼び出し履歴は、デバッグ対象が実行中であるときにリアルタイムで更新されるものではないです。仕掛けたブレイクポイントにひっかかったり、デバッグ→中断した、などデバッガに制御が戻ったときにのみ表示されます
- 上記の通り「中断」なり「ブレイク」した状態でも表示されないのなら下記

  - Release モードで実行していると表示されない、もしくは不正確な表示になります
  - Debug モードでもデバッグ情報を出力しない設定変更などすれば表示されません
  - [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) で `EXE` を作り、その中で [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) 製の `DLL` を呼ぶ場合などでは、プロジェクトのプロパティからネィティブコードデバッグを有効にするのチェックが必要かもしれません

普通に Visual Studio をインストールして使っている限りにおいて Debug モードでブレイクした状態で呼び出し履歴が表示されないってのは過去に経験が無いです。それでも表示されない場合は一度再インストール (Visual Studio の、または Windows 自体/アプリケーション群すべて) を試してみる価値はあるかもしれません。

Comment: ブレイクポイントを貼ってはじめて使える機能でした。